# Firebase file upload works for a while but then fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firebase

Can someone please assist me?

I'm using firebase to upload photos for a tour company and the file upload works well for only a while then fails and the files aren't uploaded to firebase.

```
var ImageButton = document.getElementById('ImagefileButton');
    var date = Date.now();

    ImageButton.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        $.each(e.target.files, function (idx, ele) {
            var file = e.target.files[idx];
            var firefilename = 'Images/Images/' + date +''+idx+'';
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(firefilename);

            storageRef.put(file).then(uploadImage(firefilename));

            
        })
        toastr.success('All Images Successfully uploaded!');

        setTimeout(function () {
            CloseAddImages();
        },5000)
        
    });
```

I have tried a lot of resources, to the point where my firebase bucket reached its limitations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you're building an app, things don't go as planned and an error occurs!

When in doubt, check the error handler (or catch() function for Promises), and see what the error message has to say.